# Inner Join query n:m

Tags: mysql, join

Ok i have the tables niveles, categoria and niveles_has_categoria

### idcategoria|categoria

1|Child

2|Teen

3|Adult

### idNivelCat|niveles_idniveles|categoria_idcategoria

1|1|3

2|3|2

3|3|1

4|3|3

5|2|3

The third table is a relationship n:m of the two other table, so I am trying to get by the id of the two tables the other data, this is my query

```
SELECT n.nombre_nivel, c.categoria FROM niveles n, categoria c WHERE n.idniveles in (SELECT n.idniveles FROM niveles n INNER JOIN niveles_has_categoria nc ON n.idniveles=nc.niveles_idniveles ) 

AND c.idcategoria in (SELECT c.idcategoria FROM categoria c INNER JOIN niveles_has_categoria nca ON c.idcategoria=nca.categoria_idcategoria)
```

But it shows something like this:

### nombre_nivel|categoria

Level 1|Child

Level 1|Teen

Level 1|Adult

Level 2|Child

Level 2|Teen

Level 2|Adult

Level 3|Child

Level 3|Teen

Level 3|Adult

when it should be something like this:

### nombre_nivel|categoria

Level 1|Adult

Level 3|Teen

Level 3|Child

Level 3|Adult

Level 2|Adult

If someone can help it would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select n.nombre_nivel, c.categoria from niveles_has_categoria nc 
      inner join niveles n on nc.niveles_idniveles = n.idniveles
      inner join categoria c on nc.categoria_idcategoria = c.idcategoria
```

The idea is to start with the table that has the structure you need, then only add the entries that belong attached to that record in each step.

Comment: inner join niveles n on "nc".niveles_idniveles = n.idniveles, you forgot the "c" but it works, thanks man :D